# Breakpoint at "throw new SilentExitException()" in Eclipse + Spring Boot

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, breakpoints, spring-tool-suite

Every time I run my Spring Boot project on debug mode in Eclipse IDE (Spring Tool Suite), the thread stops at `throw new SilentExitException();` line even without a breakpoint.

Is there some solution to avoid this behavior?

`org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.SilentExitExceptionHandler.exitCurrentThread() (line 53):`

```
public static void exitCurrentThread() {
    throw new SilentExitException();
}
```

This starts happening after upgrade to 1.3.0 Milestones.

**Spring Tool Suite**

```
Version: 3.7.0.RELEASE
Build Id: 201506290649
```

**Platform:**

```
Eclipse Luna SR2 (4.4.2)
```

Comment: For IntelliJ users who landed here: Add a condition to the breakpoint in Run | View Breakpoints... | Any Exceptions: `return !(this instanceof org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.SilentExitExceptionHandler.SilentExitException);` This must be Java even if you develop in another JVM language.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

This is unfortunately a know issue with the new `spring-boot-devtools` module (see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3100). We use this trick to kill the main thread so that we can replace it with a re-loadable version. So far I've not found a way to prevent the debug breakpoint from triggering.

For now, you can toggle the "suspend execution on uncaught exceptions" checkbox in Java -> Debug preferences to prevent it from happening.

Comment: This issue is still present unfortunately.

Comment: This issue is still present.

Comment: still present :p

Comment: This issue still present. using Eclipse Version: 2019-06 (4.12.0) & spring-boot 2.0.6.
Window-> Preferences -.> Java -> Debig -> unchecked "Suspend execution on uncaught exceptions"

Comment: Still present with Eclipse version 2020-03 (4.15.0) & spring-boot 2.3.1

Comment: Still present on spring boot 2.4.0 and eclipse Version: 2020-06 (4.16.0)

Comment: Well, you know, still present

Comment: And all of a sudden, it became present for me too ..

Comment: Spring Boot 2.7.1 and the issue is still present....

Comment: Still not fixed. Spring Boot 5.2.4

Comment: See next answer of @xbranko is the solution per 2022: -Dspring.devtools.restart.enabled=false when launching the debugger

Answer (score 39):

Add the property as a VM argument:

```
-Dspring.devtools.restart.enabled=false
```

[image]

That way you don't have to change your code, as it is the case when using:

```
System.setProperty("spring.devtools.restart.enabled", "false");
```

Comment: Out of other options, I used this. Thanks a lot for making my day!

Comment: Thank u for share!!! I used in the main method with:
System.setProperty("spring.devtools.restart.enabled", "false");

Comment: This works !! For silent exit without a relevant stacktrace. I also had a mysql-connector-java version issue before this which can also cause a silent exit exception. For that if you are using the 5.1.6 try switching to 5.1.49.

Answer (score 17):

As Eclipse on Debug mode already allows limited hotpatching, I find the reloader to be counterproductive most of the time and so I decided to disable it by:

```
System.setProperty("spring.devtools.restart.enabled", "false");
```

Reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html#using-boot-devtools-restart-disable

Since that exception is thrown by the reloader, this also solves this issue. Note that you'll have to use the `System.setProperty` method instead of setting it in `application.properties`.

Answer (score 5):

My workaround:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        if(e.getClass().getName().contains("SilentExitException")) {
            LOGGER.debug("Spring is restarting the main thread - See spring-boot-devtools");
        } else {
            LOGGER.error("Application crashed!", e);
        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't matter that we ignore the `SilentExitException` because the devtools are just restarting the instance with a `SilentExitException` which isn't very silent. This try block will silence it...

I had to use text matching on the class as the `SilentExitException` is private in `SilentExitExceptionHandler`.

It doesn't solve your problem with the breakpoint...

Answer (score 4):

Delete these to Unknown Exceptions & it won't break there:
[image]

Unfortunately, I haven't found a way for this to be permanent, but it should last till the next time you restart eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue while running spring boot project. I found TRY CATCH block used in Main method.

Remove the try catch block run the code. that error will not come again. like below:

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    SpringApplication.run(TrewAuthApplication.class, args);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set this in your application.properties file to true.

```
spring.devtools.restart.enabled=false
```

Also go sure that if you use a spring cloud config server, there is no propertie file  that enables this.

Comment: Thi disables live-reload in apps like vaadin when you want to debug... The user just wanted to get rid of this exception stopping him from debugging. Therefore this doesnt help getting rid of the exception, it disables the complete feature.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run devtools at scope runtime:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Setting the scope to runtime, didn't work for me.

Comment: this is not working.

Answer (score 0):

My workaround in Kotlin:

```
@JvmStatic
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  val app = SpringApplication(Application::class.java)
  try {
    app.run(*args)
  } catch (e: Exception) {
    preventNonNullExitCodeOnSilentExitException(e)
  }
}

private fun preventNonNullExitCodeOnSilentExitException(e: Exception) {
  if (e.toString().contains("SilentExitException")) {
    log.info("Ignoring Silent Exit Exception...")
    e.printStackTrace()
    return
  }
  throw e
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime this seems fixed when you use Spring Tools Suite latest. BUT when you START your application the exception still occurs and the debugger stops. Just after the first live-/hot-reload it will be ignored by STS. If you take a look at Preferences - Spring, there is a flag for this exception.