# Breakpoint at “throw new SilentExitException()” in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

Everytime I run my Spring Boot project on debug mode in Eclipse IDE (Spring Tool Suite), the thread stops at "throw new SilentExitException();" line even without a breakpoint.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32770884/breakpoint-at-throw-new-silentexitexception-in-eclipse-spring-boot

Answer (score 8):

This is a known issue.

There is a solution which is to uncheck the option under
Java->debug->suspend on uncaught exception

This is described in this article

[Breakpoint at "throw new SilentExitException()" in Eclipse + Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32770884/breakpoint-at-throw-new-silentexitexception-in-eclipse-spring-boot)

This is what I put in my original post that was converted to a comment for being trivial, which I think was a little unfair.

Answer (score 0):

Set System property while run the application

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("spring.devtools.restart.enabled", "false");//Avoid Breakpoint at “throw new SilentExitException()” in Eclipse + Spring Boot
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootApplication .class, args);
    }

}
```